# How can I change the IDE language of Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, ide

I want to change the language of the Delphi XE7 IDE from German to English. BDSSetLang.exe doesn't work for the toolbar and menu items (e.g. 'File / Open project' instead of 'Datei / Projekt öffnen').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

QUICKFIX: Move all *.de files from the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin\` to another location (so you can move them back if it does not work). If that fixes your issue, delete them.

(Or *.fr for French or *.ja for Japanese- (English is default).

Comment: You should mark the other answer as the correct answer. It is the clean way to change the language of the IDE and of the libraries.

Answer (score 16):

Use `BDSSetLang.exe` in the `bin`directory of your Delphi installation.
Did you notice that there are separate settings for the IDE UI and the Library?

Answer (score 3):

for current versions (Delphi 10.4.2), the solution [here](https://www.systemcamp.com/change-your-delphi-ide-language/) works for me:

```
>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin
>bdssetlang en
```

Comment: Sadly the answer of Nobby didn't work for me. There was only one option in the drop down. But this worked just fine.